# Making Sublime Text 2 portable on OSX

Tags: sublimetext2

I'd like to be able to run sublime from a mounted drive, but not look in the local users /Library for its settings, but instead have them on the mounted drive too. Is there a way to remap the settings to another folder or make sublime portable in this manner.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a symbolic link in the user's `~/Library/Application Support` directory. First, copy the `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2` folder to the mounted drive (for example, `/Volumes/MyDrive/Settings/Sublime Text 2`). Then, run the following commands from Terminal.app or your favorite replacement (the `$` is just the command prompt, don't type it):

```bsh
$ cd /Users/UserName/Library/Application\ Support
$ rm -rf Sublime\ Text\ 2
$ ln -s /Volumes/MyDrive/Settings/Sublime\ Text\ 2 Sublime\ Text\ 2
```

and you should be all set. The first command changes to the right directory (obviously, replace `UserName` with your user name...), the second deletes the original folder (**make sure** you've copied it before you run this!), and the third creates a symbolic link to the new folder where the old one was before.

This should work for any type of mounted drive, including USB sticks, network shares, and external hard drives, as well as Dropbox, Google Drive, and similar services.

Answer (score -1):

Just move %appdata% to Data folder in your sublime text folder (this one containing sublime_text.exe). This method works both for ST2 and ST3

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory